# How to call custom classes/methods from laravel blade view?

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I have a view that renders some dates that I want to show in different ways based on the type of client that connects to my app. Initially the dates comes from a huge json that my controller gets from a webservice/API in this format

```
YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
// 2022-03-15 18:30:00 is 20220315183000
```

what I did is to use a class/helper that I have wrote in my app folder, to manipulate how those dates looks

**CONTENT OF App/ConvertTimestamp.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Helper timestamp
 */

namespace App;

class ConvertTimestamp {

    private $timestamp;

    // Style one date
    public static function styleOne($timestamp) {

        // Some manipulation here
        /* CODE */

        return $frontDate;

    }

    // Style two date
    public static function styleTwo($timestamp) {
        
        // Some manipulation here
        /* CODE */
        
        return $realDate;

    }

}
```

what I want to do now is to call this class in my blade file, I tried different approaches, the first one was simply to open php tags inside the blade file to use the related namespace like this

**CONTENT OF resources/views/view.blade.php**

```
<?php use App\ConvertTimestamp ?>

<h2>The style one date is: </h2>
<h3>{{ ConvertTimestamp::styleOne($timestamp) }}</h3>

<h2>The style two date is: </h2>
<h3>{{ ConvertTimestamp::styleTwo($timestamp) }}</h2>
```

or to directly prepend the path to the class name in this way(I'm currently using this kind of approache)

**CONTENT OF resources/views/view.blade.php**

```
<h2>The style one date is: </h2>
<h3>{{ \App\ConvertTimestamp::styleOne($timestamp) }}</h3>

<h2>The style two date is: </h2>
<h3>{{ \App\ConvertTimestamp::styleTwo($timestamp) }}</h2>
```

so the question is, there is a better way to import classes from the controller to that specific view or to all the views, something like this

**CONTENT OF controller**

```
public function index(){
    $data = 'some data';
    return view('home', $data)->useNamespace('App\ConvertTimestamp');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put all classes in the config Laravel folder app.php aliases

```
'aliases' => [
  "ConvertTimestamp" => App\ConvertTimestamp,
]
```

Now you can use all your static functions all over the blades and controllers too.

Comment: thanks this works, but how can i make the classes accessible only on that particular view?

Comment: I have no idea about this, but in your case, you can use `Accessors & Mutators` to change the showing dates format in view.